# Kendo grid GroupHeaderTemplate button with parameter

Tags: razor, kendo-grid

I'm trying to write a group header template in Kendo Grid with title and button .

I have something like this:

```
        group: { field: "ManagerName" }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "Id", title: "Id" },
            { field: "ClientName", title: "Klient" },
            { field: "EngagementName", title: "Sprawa" },
            { field: "SubprojectName", title: "Podsprawa" },
            { field: "ManagerName", title: "Manager", groupHeaderTemplate: "#= value #    <button class='rounded-button rounded-button-blue' type='button' onclick='confirmGroup()'>@Resources.Lang.confirmGroup</button>" },
            { field: "ManagerId", title: "ManagerId", hidden: true },
            { field: "LocationName", title: "Lokalizacja" },
            { field: "Signatures", title: "Ostatnia sygnatura" },
            { field: "LogicalState", title: "Stan" }
        ]
```

And I would like to call functions confirmGroup with parameter Manager Id.
Unfortunettly something like:

```
onclick='confirmGroup(#=ManagerId#)'
```

Doesn't work.
I was looking for solution but didn't find anything.
Could anyone tell me how to call this method, please?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. can I have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Surround your parameter with escaped `"` and passing `data.ManagerId` will do the trick.

```
onclick='confirmGroup(\"#=data.ManagerId#\")'
```